# How to pass data to a component outside of the router-outlet?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add a sidebar which would contain some data from api and database. It would be some basic informations about the user's account and for ex. his friends list. My idea was to do it in similar way that I already set up a navbar - outside the router-outlet, hidden when user is not logged in.

***app.component.html***

```
<header *ngIf="userIsLogged == true">
  <app-header></app-header>
</header>
<div *ngIf="userIsLogged == true" id="animated-bar">
  <app-side-bar></app-side-bar>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

But I faced a problem with passing data to this sidebar. To provide a proper data for all views (inside router) I'm using resolvers, f.ex. like this one:

***profile.resolve.service.ts***

```
export class FriendResolve implements Resolve<FriendModel[]> {

    constructor(private _api: ApiService) {
     }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        return this._api.getFriendsList(parseInt(id));
    }
}
```

And then subscribing to it through the route:

***profile.component.ts***

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

//...

this.route.data.subscribe((data: { friends: any }) => {
  this.friendsAll = data.friends;
});
```

So now the question is how to pass data into the sidebar which is completely outside of routing? 
It should contain the same data through whole app lifecycle, no matter of URL and route. I was also trying to use another, so called, data.service to pass data from profile.component (see above) and subscribe to it in sidebar component but it didn't work at all because router and resolver seems to be starting after initialization of sidebar.

I appreciate any advice. I'm still learning so if you think that I should do it in completely different way just tell me, because I feel like I've just stucked with that approach.

**Edit:**

[image: Problematic order]

Good old way of "debuging"... ;D So now I'm trying to use a service and simply subscribe in sidebar component to the same data that I subscribe in profile inside router-outlet. And here, on screenshot above, you have an example with the order in which all things are done in this scenario. First of all service is trying to get data - not possible, there is nothing yet. After that sidebar is subscribing for this "nothing", and finally APP is successfully receiving data from API. After that resolver is letting profile component to run and it is properly subscribing the data. 
How can I make the friends.service and sidebar waiting for API response until it's not done?

Comment: You can get the data in app-component and subscribe it in sidebar component.

Comment: @Keshav can you explain what do you mean exactly?

Comment: As you have app.component,html similarly you would have app.component.ts in which u can get the data and use it in sidebar component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came out with another approach, still using a service.

You could subscribe into this service, and then use a Subject to notify components when data is ready, so service would become like this

**friends.service.ts**

```
export class FriendsService {
    get friends(): any[] {
        return this._friends;
    }

    private _friends: any[];

    private friendsSet: Subject<any[]>;
    public friendsSet$: Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
                private route: Router){
        this.friendsSet = new Subject<any[]>();
        this.friendsSet$ = this.friendsSet.asObservable();

        this.init();
    }

    private init(){
        this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
           if(data.hasOwnProperty('friends')){
               this.friendsSet.next(data['friends']);
           }
        });
    }
}
```

while components will all use the service's subject observable to be notified when friends have been loaded

profile.component.ts

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    private _friends: any[];

    constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService){

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.friendsService.friendsSet$.subscribe((friends) => {
          console.log(friends);
      });

      this._friends = this.friendsService.friends;

    }
}
```

sidebar.component.ts

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
    private _friends: any[];

    constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService){

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.friendsService.friendsSet$.subscribe((friends) => {
            console.log(friends);
        });

        this._friends = this.friendsService.friends;

    }
}
```

I did not test it, but it should work

Comment: This idea is not working for me. I've added subscription inside sidebar component also , as you said, but the value its receiving is "undefined" (at the same time profile component gets correct value). What I can see from console it is because sidebar is not waiting for resolver doing his work and in result subscribing empty field. It might be because of the fact that this resolver is defined only for profile component in routing module, when at the same time sidebar is not defined in routing module at all (because it's not connected to any specific path). Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @locust is your sidebar already there when loading profile component? it could be that `*ngIf` that is preventing the subscription to happen. Are you loading your routes using lazy loading? did you try with a service?

Comment: @locust anyway, I still recommend you the service approach, as it's more understandable and clean

Comment: Ok, so '*ngIf' is not the problem, checked. I'm not using lazy routes. I'm trying with service and it is still not working. Could you take a look at the main post? I've made an edit about this.

Comment: Finally, this approach, with needed modifications, works properly. Thank you so much for help! ;)